# bootstrap sticky footer with responsive content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There is the simple solution for sticky footer when you know the height of the footer.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

But when the footer height could change how can we solve the sticky footer

Comment: Actually, in the example you gave, there not an explicit height set on the footer.  It is expanding to the content within it.

Comment: @joshboley actually there is a height. It's on `.footer`. Right now it's set to 60px. You'd just change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the desired height of the footer remove "height: 60px" from .footer class. The footer height will now expand to fit its contents.

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

You will also need to dynamically set margin-bottom of body so it doesn't slide under the absolutely positioned footer. You can do this with javascript. Jquery example:

```
$(function(){
  var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
  $("body").css("margin-bottom", footerHeight);
  $(".footer").css("margin-top", -footerHeight);
});
```

Example here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tFcJr

There are also 2 other ways to achieve a sticky footer.
Using tables: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AlnHc
Using flexbox: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qysLg. I'm not sure how either of these would play with bootstrap though and obviously flexbox is only supported by IE10+.

Comment: Yes but now if the content of the page will be longer than screen height so it will overlap because we didn't place margin from the body to the footer

Comment: Well I looked for a solution with only CSS but this will still work so I'll mark it for others

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source code of the page you have mentioned, you will see there are actual **comments** telling you what to do to change the footer height:

```
body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
   height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I know that by I mean when you have dynamic content in your footer so you can't specify height in the css

Comment: then you would just put height: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from the bootstrap example:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

You would change the height attribute...

```
.footer {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The height of the footer is not the problem. The margin of the body is the problem